# SQL Anywhere 12 - exporting data to Excel

Tags: export, sybase, excel, sybase-sql-anywhere, sap

Do I need to install MS Office Excel on machine where is SQL Anywhere 12 server for below code to work?

Or SA 12 or Windows have MS Excel Driver builtin?

```
SELECT * FROM SalesOrders;
OUTPUT USING 'Driver=Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls);
DBQ=c:\\test\\sales.xls;
READONLY=0' INTO "newSalesData";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OUTPUT USING` format of the statement is using a ODBC driver to create/send the data to.

This means you must have a ODBC driver on the server which can create XLS files.

There is a MS Office 2007 ODBC [download available](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734) from microsoft which provides such a driver.

I don't know if there exist 64-Bit drivers (I think it must match with your dbserver 32/64bit) nor if Office 2010/2013/2016 ODBC drivers exist.

[Docu output-statement](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/output-statement.html)